# Tridion Experience Manager Loads New Pages as HTTP instead of HTTPS

Tags: experience-manager, cme, web8.5

Originally this was titled "Tridion Experience Manager New Page Error". We've now determined that new pages are not created in XPM because Tridion requests them as http instead of https.

**Steps to produce my issue:**

1. I navigate to a page
2. I click "new page"
3. I select page type
4. I fill in page name, and file name
5. I click "create page"

**In Tridion Web 8.5:**

Result:

The page "loading icon" spins for approximately 2 minutes. Then I get the following message:

[image: message saying must be unique item]

However, the page has been created in the CME:

[image: Page in CME]

In the browser console, I see the following:
[image: Issues in console]

The error message "carousel is not a function" displays before I went through these steps.

**Tridion 8.5 With Hotfixes**

Hotfixes applied:

- XPM_8.5.0.3571
- XPM_8.5.0.6084

Result:

After step 5, I only see the loading icon. It never goes away. And the browser console shows this:

[image: Cross domain error4]]

The page is also in the CME. *And* it's *published*:
[image: the page in the CME, and published]

**Setup Details**

The following microservices are HTTPS:

- Audience Manager
- Context
- Discovery
- Experience Optimization Management
- Experience Optimization Query
- Session Content
- Session Preview

The following Microservices are *not* HTTPS:

- Deployer

(We get publishing errors every time we try to make the deployer https)

IIS:

I can log in to the CMS, and my web browser shows that the CMS is properly https. However, I don't see any https bindings in

[image: Pic of IIS bindings]][6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxn0M.png)

Sites/ Topology Manager:

Topology manager shows the sites as both https and http. **However**, 
When we go into the "Sites" tab, the urls displayed are http:

[image: when I hover over the url in sites manager it is http]

**Summary of Issue(s)**

XPM without hotfixes

- none of the setup details mentioned above apply here, but...
- takes forever,
- and shows an error that a duplicate page was created.
- The definitely-not-a-duplicate page displays in the CME.

XPM *with* hotfixes

- takes less than forever,
- it only shows the loading icon,
- gets a "blocked loading mixed content" message in the browser console,
- and publishes the page.

**What we've Done:**

We've gone through the following in our QA environment (which has hotfixes):

1. Edited our JavaScript that showed an error in the console inside of XPM
2. Gone through the configuration of every.single.microservice to make sure they're set up properly.
3. Installed session-aware microservice instead of regular content service.
4. Made all of our microservices secure.
5. Reviewed Topology manager. All of our sites were set up to use both http and https.

With all of these things in our QA environment, we still have the issue. Below is a console log of the XHR requests happening during page creation. We still get a "Blocked Loading Mixed Active Content" error in the console.

**if** we disable browser security, we can created a page. So we know that it has specifically to do with the fact that Tridion is requesting a page as HTTP instead of HTTPS. What can we do to resolve this?

**Tridion Tries to load pages as http, even though:**

- Tridion is HTTPS in the browser
- The webpages it tries to load are HTTPS

It's like Tridion doesn't know it's supposed to load an https page as https:

[image: Log of all XHR requests]

Comment: Do you have any extensions or event system code active? It seems like something is trying to save the Page twice...

Comment: No extensions that I know of. (Alchemy isn't installed, no GUI extensions that I can tell)

Comment: You'll need to check on the server -- System.config for GUI extensions and Tridion.ContentManager.config for event system code.

Comment: no GUI extensions whatsoever

Comment: Also no event system?

Comment: Best that I can tell, this install of Tridion wasn't modified _at all_. 

Our latest working theory is that we need to install some XPM hotfixes, and _also_ set up XPM tor work w/ SSL.

Comment: 1. Is that behavior just for one page or other pages creation also? 
2. How about this behavior if you are creating the page directly on CMS without XPM?
3. Is that preview service configured correctly with preview XPM database?
4. Double check Is there any custom workflow event system code is there anything deployed?

Comment: @Velmurugan 1) All pages. 
2) We have no issue creating pages outside of XPM. 
3) We've gone through all of our configurations. They are correct
4) No custom workflows or event system code. This is as out-of-the-box as it can get. our production cms has no hotfixes.

Comment: In general if the CMS is running in HTTPS, you must deploy your XPM (Staging) site as HTTPS, same goes for HTTP, since browsers don't like mixed content anymore. I'm wondering if this is where your issues are coming from, since the Web 8.5 server we use has no hotfixes and seems to be working just fine (XPM always was slow of course)

Comment: How is Topology Manager configured, does that use HTTPS base URLs? When you go to the Sites section in the CMS or when you view a Page on Staging or Live, does it open an HTTPS URL for that?

Comment: @BartKoopman Topology manager uses https URLs. *However* , when I go to "sites", they're all http. Adding a screengrab, above.

Answer (score 4):

You mentioned “Topology Manager shows the sites as both HTTP and HTTPS” (technically speaking: the Websites have multiple Base URLs).
The question is: which one is first? The first Base URL of a Website (aka Primary Base URL) is used in some places in the CME (e.g. the “View on Site” feature) and may also be used by XPM.

So: your problem might be that the HTTP URL is the first Base URL in Topology Manager.

Comment: After weeks of working on this issue, I did a screenshare with SDL Support and one of my team mates caught that the publishing settings for our publications were for http. And I remembered that our topology manager export listed HTTP and HTTPS urls. But the HTTPS base urls were listed _second_. 

So this, indeed, seems like the root cause. We reached this conclusion about an hour ago. Your answer definitely confirms it. 

How can we fix this? Just switch the order in topology manager?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, use set-ttmwebsite commandlet to change the order
Set-TtmWebsite -Id website1 -BaseUrls @("https://some_url:port", "http://some_url:port")

Comment: what's the fallout from running that? will I need to republish? unpublish? sacrifice a woodland creature to Freja?